# The customer was prevented from spending money and (was?) advised to save a certain amount daily

Tags: exam-questions, conjunction-reduction

> The customer was prevented from spending money and **was** advised to save a certain amount daily.

Can the **was** in above sentence removed and the sentence still be grammatically correct ? Sorry this is a very basic question but I don't know what this 'concept' is known as in grammar so couldn't search for it on google and had to post it here on SE.

Comment: Predictions can be conjoined. So the sentence is OK. Try looking up 'conjunction reduction'.

Answer (score 1):

**It can be removed and still be correct.**

The reason this can be removed is that the tense is already given by the first "was" in the sentence. The second "was" gives the tense for the advice, but since it remains in the same tense we don't necessarily need to specify it.